# Android - String comparison between two android version names

Tags: android

As the android version names are in String data type, I want to compare the existing apk on my device with the new apk update version name. I know how to get the version name programmatically and I have two version names but string comparision between two version names does not show correct result

```
if ( oldVersionName.compareTo( newVersionName ) < 0 ) {
}
```

This compareTo does not work in few scenarioes like 1.0.9 and 1.0.12, 1.0.9 and 1.0.10.

Please give me solution on how to compare two string version names programatically? Thank you!

Comment: why not use the versionCode?

Comment: I agree that versionCode is integer but still when we go to apps -> setting -> myapp, there version name is visible to user not the version code value

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get the 'int form' of Android versions using

```
 Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

Anyway, if all you have is version names in 'dot notation', you can `split` the strings by '.' char, and iterate to compare part by part. Off the top of my head, it'd look something like.-

```
public int compareVersionNames(String oldVersionName, String newVersionName) {
    int res = 0;

    String[] oldNumbers = oldVersionName.split("\\.");
    String[] newNumbers = newVersionName.split("\\.");

    // To avoid IndexOutOfBounds
    int maxIndex = Math.min(oldNumbers.length, newNumbers.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i ++) {
        int oldVersionPart = Integer.valueOf(oldNumbers[i]);
        int newVersionPart = Integer.valueOf(newNumbers[i]);

        if (oldVersionPart < newVersionPart) {
            res = -1;
            break;
        } else if (oldVersionPart > newVersionPart) {
            res = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If versions are the same so far, but they have different length...
    if (res == 0 && oldNumbers.length != newNumbers.length) {
        res = (oldNumbers.length > newNumbers.length)?1:-1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Just wrote without trying it, so sure can be optimized, but it's a start.

Comment: Build.VERSION.SDK_INT gives the SDK version but I wanted to compare android app version names

Comment: Just edited my answer. Couldn't test the code, so sorry for any typos

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I got an idea .. but the above method was incomplete, I just added a boolean return type to see if oldversion name is greater than newversion name but the return values doesn't seeem to be right and I am not really good in this comparision, if possible can I get the working code snippet which is working one

Comment: I missed escape characters for `split` method. Now it should work. Keep in mind that this method will return an int: -1 if first arg is < than the second one, 1 on the contrary, and 0 if they are equal.

Comment: It's working, I am just clear about the result.                                                // 1 : Old version in higher then new    // -1: Old version lover then new  //  0: Both are equal

Answer (score 4):

newVersion = 1.2.1 -> 121 -> 121

oldVersion = 1.2   -> 12  -> 120

121 > 120 ?

return true

---

newVersion = 1.5.15 -> 1515 -> 1515

oldVersion = 2.0    -> 20   -> 2000

1515 > 2000 ?

return false

```
public static boolean checkForUpdate(String existingVersion, String newVersion) {
    if (existingVersion.isEmpty() || newVersion.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    existingVersion = existingVersion.replaceAll("\\.", "");
    newVersion = newVersion.replaceAll("\\.", "");

    int existingVersionLength = existingVersion.length();
    int newVersionLength = newVersion.length();

    StringBuilder versionBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (newVersionLength > existingVersionLength) {
        versionBuilder.append(existingVersion);
        for (int i = existingVersionLength; i < newVersionLength; i++) {
            versionBuilder.append("0");
        }
        existingVersion = versionBuilder.toString();
    } else if (existingVersionLength > newVersionLength){
        versionBuilder.append(newVersion);
        for (int i = newVersionLength; i < existingVersionLength; i++) {
            versionBuilder.append("0");
        }
        newVersion = versionBuilder.toString();
    }

    return Integer.parseInt(newVersion) > Integer.parseInt(existingVersion);
}
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!

Comment: As @Dexter commented in the next post: "This solution though efficient wouldn't work in certain edge cases. For example, if we compare version numbers like 10.1.0 and 9.10.0 or 1.10.1 and 11.0.1 it would give a wrong result."

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` you have to specify an integer [versionCode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#vcode) as well as a string [versionName](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#vname). Both values can be retrieved at runtime so you should use `versionCode` instead of `versionName` for comparing app versions.

If you want to retrieve the `versionCode` of your own app you can use the following code:

```
public static int getAppVersionCode(Context context) {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageInfo(context);
    return packageInfo.versionCode;
}

private static PackageInfo getPackageInfo(Context context) {
    try {
        return context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    }
    catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

Version codes of other apps can be retrieved by providing the correct package name.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with the following code:

```
    String VERSION_TO_COMPARE = "1.2.3"   

    try {

        //get current Version Code
        PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
        String currentVersionName = info.versionName;

        if(!VERSION_TO_COMPARE.equals(currentVersionName)){
            //version string not the same, version is NOT up to date

            Boolean updateNeeded = false;
            String[] currentVersionCodeArray = currentVersionName.split("\\.");
            String[] storeVersionCodeArray = VERSION_TO_COMPARE.split("\\.");

            int maxLength = currentVersionCodeArray.length;
            if(storeVersionCodeArray.length > maxLength){
                maxLength = storeVersionCodeArray.length;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++){

                try{
                    if(Integer.parseInt(storeVersionCodeArray[i]) > Integer.parseInt(currentVersionCodeArray[i])){
                        updateNeeded = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                    //store version code length > current version length = version needs to be updated
                    //if store version length is shorter, the if-statement already did the job
                    if(storeVersionCodeArray.length > currentVersionCodeArray.length){
                        updateNeeded = true;
                    }
                }


            }

            if(updateNeeded){
                //current version of app, lower than VERSION_TO_COMPARE
                //do sth. in our case, show an update-dialog
            }

        }
        else{
            //do nothing: version is up to date
        }

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

/**
  * The method compares the two APK versions and returns true, If existing is smaller/Older then new version.
  *
  * @param existingVersion the version which validates against `newVersion`.
  * @param newVersion      the version which may be updated recently in the one drive or in the playstore.
  */

```
 public static boolean checkForUpdate(String existingVersion, String newVersion) {
     if (TextUtils.isEmpty(existingVersion) || TextUtils.isEmpty(newVersion)) {
         return false;
     }
     boolean newVersionIsGreater = false;
     String[] existingVersionArray = existingVersion.split("\\.");
     String[] newVersionArray = newVersion.split("\\.");

     int maxIndex = Math.max(existingVersionArray.length, newVersionArray.length);
     for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++) {
         int newValue;
         int oldValue;
         try {
             oldValue = Integer.parseInt(existingVersionArray[i]);
         } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
             oldValue = 0;
         }
         try {
             newValue = Integer.parseInt(newVersionArray[i]);
         } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
             newValue = 0;
         }
         if (oldValue < newValue) {
             newVersionIsGreater = true;
             continue;
         }
     }
     return newVersionIsGreater;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small Android library for exactly that: https://github.com/G00fY2/version-compare

What it basically does is this:

```
  public int compareVersions(String versionA, String versionB) {
    String[] versionTokensA = versionA.split("\\.");
    String[] versionTokensB = versionB.split("\\.");
    List<Integer> versionNumbersA = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> versionNumbersB = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String versionToken : versionTokensA) {
      versionNumbersA.add(Integer.parseInt(versionToken));
    }
    for (String versionToken : versionTokensB) {
      versionNumbersB.add(Integer.parseInt(versionToken));
    }

    final int versionASize = versionNumbersA.size();
    final int versionBSize = versionNumbersB.size();
    int maxSize = Math.max(versionASize, versionBSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
      if ((i < versionASize ? versionNumbersA.get(i) : 0) > (i < versionBSize ? versionNumbersB.get(i) : 0)) {
        return 1;
      } else if ((i < versionASize ? versionNumbersA.get(i) : 0) < (i < versionBSize ? versionNumbersB.get(i) : 0)) {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

This snippet doesn't offer any error checks or handling. Beside that my library also supports suffixes like "1.2-rc" > "1.2-beta".

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler solution with Kotlin.

It supports version compare with non digit chars and version number larger than 10 like the below cases.

"1.0.0".compareToVersion("1.0.0") `result = 0`

"1.0.0c".compareToVersion("1.0.0b") `result > 0`

"1.0.10".compareToVersion("1.0.9c") `result > 0`

"1.0.10-1".compareToVersion("1.0.10-2") `result < 0`

"10.0.1a".compareToVersion("9.0.10a") `result > 0`

```kotlin
fun String.compareToVersion(version: String): Int {
    // Split with non-digit char
    val pattern = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]")
    val inputVersionSplit = version.split(pattern)

    // Convert each block as Int and return the first return that is not equal
    split(pattern).mapIndexed { index, thisVersionSub ->
        thisVersionSub.toIntOrNull()
            ?.compareTo(inputVersionSplit.getOrNull(index)?.toIntOrNull() ?: 0)
            ?.takeIf { it != 0 }
            ?.also { return it }
    }

    // If version splits are identical, compare by String
    return compareTo(version)
}
```

[examples](https://pl.kotl.in/riW6G_SvF)

Comment: why its minus? is it not working?

Comment: sorry, I made a typo. corrected the answer and provided an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkVersion() {
    boolean isLastVersion = false;
    Double lastVersion = convertVersion(getAppVersion());
    Double runningVersion = convertVersion(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);

    if (runningVersion >= lastVersion) {
        isLastVersion = true;
    }

    return isLastVersion;
}
public Double convertVersion(String version) {
    Double convertedVersion = 0.0;

    version = version.replace(".", "");
    String versionAux1 = version.substring(0,1);
    String versionAux2 = version.substring(1, version.length());

    version = versionAux1 + "." + versionAux2;
    convertedVersion = Double.valueOf(version);
    return convertedVersion;
}
```

getAppVersion() returns version to compare

convertVersion(String version) converts a String value with none, one or more dots to a Double value

Answer (score 0):

Above all solutions didn't work for me. So I have another solution for you all

**1. Use this class:**

```
public class VersionComparator implements Comparator {

public boolean equals(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return compare(o1, o2) == 0;
}

public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    String version1 = (String) o1;
    String version2 = (String) o2;

    VersionTokenizer tokenizer1 = new VersionTokenizer(version1);
    VersionTokenizer tokenizer2 = new VersionTokenizer(version2);

    int number1, number2;
    String suffix1, suffix2;

    while (tokenizer1.MoveNext()) {
        if (!tokenizer2.MoveNext()) {
            do {
                number1 = tokenizer1.getNumber();
                suffix1 = tokenizer1.getSuffix();
                if (number1 != 0 || suffix1.length() != 0) {
                    // Version one is longer than number two, and non-zero
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            while (tokenizer1.MoveNext());

            // Version one is longer than version two, but zero
            return 0;
        }

        number1 = tokenizer1.getNumber();
        suffix1 = tokenizer1.getSuffix();
        number2 = tokenizer2.getNumber();
        suffix2 = tokenizer2.getSuffix();

        if (number1 < number2) {
            // Number one is less than number two
            return -1;
        }
        if (number1 > number2) {
            // Number one is greater than number two
            return 1;
        }

        boolean empty1 = suffix1.length() == 0;
        boolean empty2 = suffix2.length() == 0;

        if (empty1 && empty2) continue; // No suffixes
        if (empty1) return 1; // First suffix is empty (1.2 > 1.2b)
        if (empty2) return -1; // Second suffix is empty (1.2a < 1.2)

        // Lexical comparison of suffixes
        int result = suffix1.compareTo(suffix2);
        if (result != 0) return result;

    }
    if (tokenizer2.MoveNext()) {
        do {
            number2 = tokenizer2.getNumber();
            suffix2 = tokenizer2.getSuffix();
            if (number2 != 0 || suffix2.length() != 0) {
                // Version one is longer than version two, and non-zero
                return -1;
            }
        }
        while (tokenizer2.MoveNext());

        // Version two is longer than version one, but zero
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

// VersionTokenizer.java
public static class VersionTokenizer {
    private final String _versionString;
    private final int _length;

    private int _position;
    private int _number;
    private String _suffix;
    private boolean _hasValue;

    VersionTokenizer(String versionString) {
        if (versionString == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("versionString is null");

        _versionString = versionString;
        _length = versionString.length();
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return _number;
    }

    String getSuffix() {
        return _suffix;
    }

    public boolean hasValue() {
        return _hasValue;
    }

    boolean MoveNext() {
        _number = 0;
        _suffix = "";
        _hasValue = false;

        // No more characters
        if (_position >= _length)
            return false;

        _hasValue = true;

        while (_position < _length) {
            char c = _versionString.charAt(_position);
            if (c < '0' || c > '9') break;
            _number = _number * 10 + (c - '0');
            _position++;
        }

        int suffixStart = _position;

        while (_position < _length) {
            char c = _versionString.charAt(_position);
            if (c == '.') break;
            _position++;
        }

        _suffix = _versionString.substring(suffixStart, _position);

        if (_position < _length) _position++;

        return true;
    }
}
```

}

**2. create this function**

```
    private fun isNewVersionAvailable(currentVersion: String, latestVersion: String): Boolean {
    val versionComparator = VersionComparator()
    val result: Int = versionComparator.compare(currentVersion, latestVersion)
    var op = "=="
    if (result < 0) op = "<"
    if (result > 0) op = ">"
    System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", currentVersion, op, latestVersion)
    return if (op == ">" || op == "==") {
        false
    } else op == "<"
}
```

**3. and just call it by**

e.g. `isNewVersionAvailable("1.2.8","1.2.9")` where `1.2.8` is your current version here and `1.2.9` is the latest version, which returns true!

**Happy Coding!**

Answer (score 0):

//this is a c# version however you can easily convert into java

//return 0 if both versions are same, return 1 if version1 is greater and return -1 if version1 is lower

```
    public int compareVersionCode(string version1,string version2,char spliteType='.')
    {

        string[] version1A = version1.Split(spliteType);
        string[] version2A = version2.Split(spliteType);



        // To avoid IndexOutOfBounds
        int maxIndex = Math.Min(version1A.Length, version2A.Length);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++)
        {
            int v1 = int.Parse(version1A[i]);
            int v2 = int.Parse(version2A[i]);

            if (v1 < v2)
            {
               return -1;
            }
            else if (v1 > v2)
            {
                return  1;
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I have tested again and again, Have a Good Day :)

```
private void checkVersion(String[] expVersion, String[] curVersion) {

    Integer[] remoteConfigVer = new Integer[3];

    for (int j = 0; j < expVersion.length; j++) {
        remoteConfigVer[j] = Integer.valueOf(expVersion[j]);
    }

    Integer[] curVers = new Integer[3];

    for (int j = 0; j < curVersion.length; j++) {
        curVers[j] = Integer.valueOf(curVersion[j]);
    }

    if (remoteConfigVer[0] == curVers[0]) {
        if (remoteConfigVer[1] == curVers[1]) {
            if (remoteConfigVer[2] == curVers[2]) {

                // no update required
                postContactForVehicleONLOAD(pphone);
                Toast.makeText(context, "This is the latest version", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (remoteConfigVer[2] < curVers[2]) {

                // no update required
                postContactForVehicleONLOAD(pphone);
                Toast.makeText(context, "This is the latest version", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (remoteConfigVer[2] > curVers[2]) {

                // update required
                showCustomAlertDialogue();
            }
        } else if (remoteConfigVer[1] < curVers[1]) {

            // no update required
            postContactForVehicleONLOAD(pphone);
            Toast.makeText(context, "This is the latest version", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (remoteConfigVer[1] > curVers[1]) {

            // update required
            showCustomAlertDialogue();

        }
    } else if (remoteConfigVer[0] < curVers[0]) {

        // no update required
        postContactForVehicleONLOAD(pphone);
        Toast.makeText(context, "This is the latest version", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (remoteConfigVer[0] > curVers[0]) {

        // update required
        showCustomAlertDialogue();

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the version in string so remove . in that and convert to float and compare

```
onlineVersion = onlineVersion.replace(".", "");
currentVersion = currentVersion.replace(".", "");

if (Float.valueOf(currentVersion) < Float.valueOf(onlineVersion)) {
    //if new update is available it will come here
}
```

Comment: This solution though efficient wouldn't work in certain edge cases. For example if we compare version numbers like 10.1.0 and 9.10.0 or 1.10.1 and 11.0.1 it would give a wrong result.